# Apertar button com a tecla enter do teclado

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Possuo um botão gravar em meu site, gostaria de que ao apertar a tecla "Enter" do teclado esse botão seja acionado, como se fosse um click do mouse, existe alguma função para fazer isso?

Código do botão:

```
<button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary btn-sucesso" onclick="parent.fecharJanelas('ListaBancos')"><i class="far fa-check-circle"></i> Gravar</button>
```

Esse botão chama uma função de uma classe pai, quero que ao clicar o `enter` o `parent.fecharJanelas('ListaBancos')` seja executado

Esse é meu botão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
<button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary btn-atualizar" onclick="window.location.reload()"><i class="fas fa-undo-alt"></i> Atualizar</button>

<button type="reset" id="btnFecharJanelas" class="btn btn-primary btn-sucesso" onkeypress="parent.fecharJanelas('ListaBancos')"><i class="far fa-check-circle"></i> Gravar</button>

<button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary btn-sair" onclick="parent.fecharJanela('ListaBancos')"></button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-incluir button" onclick="parent.geradorCodigo('FrmGrdBanco', 'Tabela de Bancos', '/Bancos/Index', 980, 443);"></button>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(this.window).keypress(function () {
            $("#btnFecharJanelas").trigger("click");
        });
    });

    function selection_changed(selectedItems) {
        var data = selectedItems.selectedRowsData[0];
        if (data) {
            $('input[name="IdAgencia"]').val(data["Ban_Codigo"]);
            parent.codigoBanco = data["Ban_Codigo"];
            parent.nomeBanco = data["Ban_Nome"];
            parent.paginaBanco = data["Ban_Site"];
        }
    }




    function Cadastrar() {
        geradorCodigo("FrmGrdBanco", "Tabela de Bancos", "/Bancos/Index", 980, 443);
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

É bastante possível utilizando apenas javascript.

**Utilizando KeyboardEvent**

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if(e.key == "Enter"){
      document.getElementById("btFechar").click();
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btFechar" onclick="alert('Putz, alguém me bateu!');" />
```

**Utilizando onkeypress**

```js
function checkMyKey(e) {
  var keyCode;
  //  Browsers de verdade
  if(e.which){
    keyCode = e.which;
  }
  // Internet Explorer
  else if(window.event){
    keyCode = e.keyCode;
  }
  if (keyCode == 13) {
    document.getElementById("btFechar").click(); 
  }
}
```

```html
<body onkeypress="return checkMyKey(event);">
  <input type="button" id="btFechar" onclick="alert('Putz, alguém me bateu!');" />
</body>
```

Comment: Eu gostei utilizando javascript, porém qualquer tecla que eu aperte chama a função

Comment: Atualizei a resposta!

Comment: Agora está funcionando apenas com o click do mouse

Comment: Tá executando na sua página ou utilizando o "Executar" aqui? Testei as duas soluções e tá tranquilo (até no Microsoft Edge...)

Comment: Estou usando o executar daqui mesmo, utilizo o google chrome, vou testar em outro navegador

Comment: Estranho, nem no edge foi, vou testar no meu projeto

Comment: Ah, desculpe, burrice minha, seu código resolve meu problema, obrigado

Answer (score 11):

Abaixo uma forma usando JQuery:

**Botão:**

```
<button type="reset" id="btnFecharJanelas" class="btn btn-primary btn-sucesso" onkeypress="fecharJanelas('ListaBancos')"><i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>Gravar</button>
```

**JQuery:**

```
jQuery(document.body).on('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#btnFecharJanelas").trigger("click");
    }
});
```

Assim em qualquer parte do documento que o usuário apertar Enter irá chamar o botão.

O `e.keyCode === 13` indica que a tecla Enter foi pressionada

O `e.preventDefault()` previne que seja feito um `postback` da página

O `("#btnFecharJanelas").trigger("click");` chama o evento *click* do botão

Você pode também definir que isso ocorra em apenas um escopo, como um *form*, exemplo:

```
jQuery(document.body).on('keypress', '#myForm', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#btnFecharJanelas").trigger("click");
    }
});
```

Comment: Desculpe a demora, é que estive envolvido em outra parte, essa função é boa, mas, tem um problema, eu tenho q apertar o botão "gravar" para só então consegui apertar o enter, não sei explicar o porque, mas amanhã posto o código todo na pergunta

Answer (score -1):

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if(e.key == "Enter"){
      document.getElementById("btFechar").click();
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btFechar" onclick="alert('Putz, alguém me bateu!');" />
```

Answer (score -2):

Usando somente JavaScript 
Quando o usuário pressionar a tecla Enter do teclado a função vai ser executada.

Qualquer logica que esteja dentro da função vai ser executada, nesse exemplo coloquei um simples alerta

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button type="reset" onkeypress="btnFechar()"><i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>Gravar</button>

<script>

function btnFechar() {
  alert("Faz alguma coisa aqui");
parent.fecharJanelas('ListaBancos');
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: e como esse código faz o que foi perguntado *"com a tecla enter do teclado"*?

Comment: O ´´´´onkeypress´´´´ funciona igualmente ao ´´´´onclick´´´´, porem para quando o usuário pressionar a tecla Enter, quando você atrela uma função a esse evento, tecnicamente você pode fazer qualquer logica dentro dessa função, até mesmo chamar outra função para ser executada.

Comment: Antônio, seu código em nenhum momento trata o pressionar enter, nada mais faz que conectar ao evento *keypress*, sua resposta ainda não responde ao ponto principal da pergunta, talvez por isso tenha alguns *downvotes*. Comento só pra ajudar que deixes uma resposta que ajude a quem perguntou e também os outros usuários. Inclua também a explicação do comentário acima que você fez na pergunta para melhorar o entendimento ;)

Comment: Com o onkeypress, eu preciso clicar no botão primeiro, pra só então depois poder apertar alguma tecla do teclado, e ai qualquer tecla que clicar executa a função, não é isso que estava querendo, mas obg pela resposta